# Getting error for master page 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am getting error for jQuery datepicker with master page and content page.

The same  jQuery datepicker  is working without any issue in page which is independent without/ not part of master page. Tried various solution provided with online but did not help.  Please help me to resolve the issue.

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'datepicker'

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head  >
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>ModularAdmin - Free Dashboard Theme | HTML Version </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor.css">
    <!-- Theme initialization -->
    <script>
        var themeSettings = (localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('themeSettings')) :
            {};
        var themeName = themeSettings.themeName || '';
        if (themeName) {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app-' + themeName + '.css">');
        }
        else {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style" href="css/app.css">');
        }
        </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>


                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="Server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="app" id="app">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="header-block header-block-collapse hidden-lg-up">
                    <button class="collapse-btn" id="sidebar-collapse-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="header-block header-block-buttons">
                </div>
                <div class="header-block header-block-nav">
                    <ul class="nav-profile">
```

Content page / Client

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<%--    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>--%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#<%=TEXTBX_DISP_DT1.ClientID%>").datepicker();

          });
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

     <form runat="server" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="new_user" method="post">
     <asp:TextBox ID="TEXTBX_DISP_DT1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How first two queries in the post are related to JavaScript and DateTime? Tried removing `jquery-1.7.1.js` from master page?

Comment: you have included jquery twice in a page <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>, remove one of them  and give try that should resolve

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Still no success tried removing java script and getting same error. On removing jquery-1.7.1.js getting error    0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined.   With only java script reference  <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js") %>"></script>   getting same error datepicker method not supported